# ! object 'long' not found while plotting shp using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have this simple code to read shp file and plot in 3D.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)    # for fortifying shapefiles
nc <- st_read("shp/polygons.shp")
#plot(st_zm(nc), max.plot = 1)
shapefile_df <- fortify(nc)
map <- ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = shapefile_df, 
            aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),
            color = 'gray', fill = 'white', size = .2)

print(map)
```

but I am getting an error

```
    Error in `geom_path()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `FUN()`:
! object 'long' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Here is the nc object

[image]

Comment: You are referring to `long` in the `aes()` call.  Look at `names(shapefile_df)` to see what names are available, because apparently `long` is not.

Comment: You can plot sf objects directly in ggplot. Just use `ggplot(nc) + geom_sf()`

Comment: @AllanCameron this does print the shp file but in 2d. I am looking for 3d visualization based on z coordinate of a polygon. Is it possible?

Comment: @user1298426 ggplot is a 2D plotting library. You can color the polygons according to their z variable, but if you want a true 3d map then you will need to look elsewhere, for example the rayshader package

Comment: another option is using [mapdeck to show elevation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60049642/4002530)